# Ruby Gtk Dialog not closing

Tags: ruby, gtk

My gtk dialog windows never close until the last task of the program.

```
dialog = Gtk::Dialog.new(
    "Test dialog",
    nil,
    Gtk::Dialog::MODAL,
    [ Gtk::Stock::OK, Gtk::Dialog::RESPONSE_OK ],
    [ Gtk::Stock::CANCEL, Gtk::Dialog::RESPONSE_CANCEL ]
)
```

And the windows destroy

```
dialog.run do |response|
case response
  when Gtk::Dialog::RESPONSE_OK
# do some minor things here
File.user # file class for method user
  end
end
dialog.destroy
}
```

As i said the problem is the windows only close when all task are completed in the `File.user` class method.I want to close the windows before all the task are ended.I try that but without success

```
dialog.run do |response|
case response
  when Gtk::Dialog::RESPONSE_OK
# do some minor things here
dialog.destroy
File.user # file class for method user
  end
end
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using `dialog.signal_connect('response') { dialog.destroy }` instead of use `dialog.destroy` only.